# SharePoint 2013 hosted APP. Cross domain issue

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am developing SharePoint hosted app. In this application i want to "Post" data (multiple file streams as multipart form data) to the cross domain third party Rest Service which needs username and password to pass with this POST request. I found many samples which can access the cross domain REST service with "GET" operation with no username and password. These samples work fine with GET operation and no username and password but not support my case where i want to send Username and Password and multipart form data.

I have seen the fiddler session and i though to send the Authorization header value which is the hash value of username and password combine. but this effort could not successfully passed the username and password to the rest service. Also i need to find a way to send the multipart form data to the REST service.

following is the question asked at msdn forum,
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d4302523-82cc-4732-a89b-05eb0bbafadf/sharepoint-2013-hosted-app-cross-domain-issue

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if your issue has been resolved yet but following are add, delete and update item in a list examples for a sharepoint hosted app making cross domain calls to a sharepoint list.

```
function addItem() {
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

var dataTobeSent = {
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.TestListforAppListItem" },
    Title: $("#col1").val(),
    testCol1: $("#col2").val(),
    test_x0020_col_x0020_2: $("#col3").val()
};

var sendData = JSON.stringify(dataTobeSent);

executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url:
            appweburl +
            "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('testListforApp')/items?@target='" +
            hostweburl + "'",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        method: "POST",
        body: sendData,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: getAllListItems,
        error: errorHandler
    }
);
}

function deleteItem(id) {
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url:
            appweburl +
            "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('testListforApp')/items(" + id + ")?@target='" +
            hostweburl + "'",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-Http-Method": "DELETE",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: getAllListItems,
        error: errorHandler
    }
);
}

function updateItem(id) {
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

var dataTobeSent = {
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.TestListforAppListItem" },
    Title: $("#col1").val(),
    testCol1: $("#col2").val(),
    test_x0020_col_x0020_2: $("#col3").val()
};

var sendData = JSON.stringify(dataTobeSent);

executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url:
            appweburl +
            "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('testListforApp')/items(" + id + ")?@target='" +
            hostweburl + "'",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        method: "POST",
        body: sendData,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: getAllListItems,
        error: errorHandler
    }
);
}
```

Hope this helps.